# django avoid duplicate model entries?

Tags: django, django-models

Below is my code snippet for a simple counting task using django models: if a product_id already exists, increment the counter for that id by 1. If the product_id does not exist yet, initiate a product instance with count=1. In runtime, the product_id's are gathered from request URLs of my web application.

```
if Counter.objects.filter(product=product_id).exists(): 
    temp = Counter.objects.filter(product=product_id)[0]
    temp.count += 1
    temp.save()
else:
    temp = Counter(product=product_id, count=1)
    temp.save()
```

However, the resulting database has some duplicate entries.

```
id,product_id,count
1446,CY8C,1
1450,6698,2
1445,0F99,39
1462,3666,1
1458,NYJJ,1
1459,NYJJ,1
1460,NYJJ,1
1457,NYJJ,2
1451,G99Q,3
1461,V727,1
1456,5LDM,3
1465,5NNQ,5
```

Did I miss anything in the code? In the django model template, I have already specified `product_id = models.TextField(unique=True)`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: please post the `View`, where you get `product_id` from the request.

Comment: lots of a few possibilites for the bad data in the database here - For example, are you stripping the contents of product_id before you do the filter ?

Comment: First, product_id is unique, use objects.get()

Comment: @Steve are you sure `product_id` is unique? Because I don't think so, maybe you have just specified `unique=True` in models but has not yet created the migrations for it and ran it (you have to remove duplicates first manually in order to apply that migration). Try to run `./manage.py makemigrations myapp` and see if Django detects some changes.

Comment: @AamirAdnan you were spot on! `makemigrations` was the punchline.